# Unity, XCode5.0.2 and iOS7 app submission problems

Tags: ios7, unity-game-engine, xcode5, submission

i created an app in unity, made the .apk for android and submitted to google play.
everything worked fine and without issues.

now i want to do the same for iOS and i only have problems! after breaking up my head with certificates and profiles i finally managed to run my app on my ipad and on the iOS simulator and finally tried to submit it to the appstore, just to realize that apple only allows iOS 7 apps and Xcode 5 since february 2014.

okaaay, so i downloaded xcode 5 and the iOS 7 sdk and submitted the app to the appstore. but now i got the next problem and i dont know how to solve it:

http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag296/marauderkr/Bildschirmfoto2014-03-07um11047PM_zpsd9742709.png

i read a tutorial how to add the missing app icons. it said i should add the png files in my folder and add lines to the info.plist with the image names. so i did this:

(adding lines to the plist after adding pngs to the "library" folder)

http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag296/marauderkr/Bildschirmfoto2014-03-07um11155PM_zps2e86dcb6.png

but is till get the same error. i dont know what to do as i am not into xcode (only into c#/unity)

i hope someone can help. maybe its just some stupid thing i am doing wrong?
(sorry for the links but stackoverflow says i cant post pictures before reputation 10+ and this is my first post...)

EDIT: problem solved!
it seems like the problem is solved! i found old xcode 3 versions on my desk and it seems like something interfered with the new ios 7 sdk OR the new xcode 5 stuff. anyway, it works now!
so if anyone else encounters this problem - be sure to absolutely have deinstalled all old xcode versions. it helped to delete the old stuff and the old sdk. i now run xcode 5.1 and the ios7 sdk and the latest unity update 4.3.4 everything works!

Comment: Though important, the lack of app icons should not prevent submission; the error "This bundle is not valid...must be built with public" is more likely the cause of invalidation. Double check your provisioning profiles, and see if you can post a screen shot of your build settings so we can narrow the problem down.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i checked the profiles and even created a new distribution profile to archive+validate it but still i get the error. posting all build settings are many screens but here is the first screen to start off: http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag296/marauderkr/Bildschirmfoto2014-03-11um104217AM_zps92151cbc.png .... maybe u already see an error there. as i said im not very much into xcode, maybe its just some flag i missed or something!

Comment: nvm, it seems like the problem is solved! i found old xcode 3 versions on my desk and it seems like something interfered with the new ios 7 sdk OR the new xcode 5 stuff. anyway, it works now!

Comment: Very cool, that is nice to hear!